# Custom Bean not loaded in Spring Boot Cloud AutoConfiguration Class

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-config

I want to provide a specific *Bean*, so that this *Bean* overrides the *Bean* in a Spring Cloud *AutoConfiguration* class.

**First try**

Therefore I've created a *Configuration* class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyLocalConfig {
  @Bean
  public ApiClient apiClient() throws IOException {
    return ClientBuilder.standard(false).build();
  }
}
```

Prioritizing by using `@Primary` or `@Order` annotations does not help.

**Second try (EDIT)**

I also tried to use an *AutoConfiguration*. But even the `@AutoConfigureBefore` Annotation is ignored.

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureBefore(KubernetesClientAutoConfiguration.class)
public class LocalKubeAutoConfiguration {
  @Bean
  public ApiClient apiClient() throws IOException {
    return ClientBuilder.standard(false).build();
  }
}
```

My *Configuration* class *Beans* are always instantiated **after** the *Beans* in *KubernetesClientAutoConfiguration* class.
Therefore the *AutoConfiguration* class does not use my *Bean*.

The doc says: [At any point, you can start to define your own configuration to replace specific parts of the auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.4.5/reference/html/using-spring-boot.html#using-boot-auto-configuration).

Questions:

- What's my mistake?
- How can I prioritize the configurations?

---

Here's my other code:

Main Class

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootAdminApp {
  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(SpringBootAdminApp.class, args);
  }
}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.4.5</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>testme</artifactId>
    <version>1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-kubernetes-client-all</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: What is the package of your configuration and what is the package of your @SpringBootApplication annotated class?

Comment: You could try to use `@Import` your configuration in your `@SpringBootApplication` class

Comment: @VladimirShefer Package of SpringBootApplication class and configuration is the same. Import doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring Boot Cloud uses [Bootstrap Configuration](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-commons/multi/multi__spring_cloud_context_application_context_services.html) to load the configurations.

> By default, bootstrap properties (not bootstrap.properties but
> properties that are loaded during the bootstrap phase) are added with
> high precedence, so they cannot be overridden by local configuration.

Therefore I have to add a BootstrapConfiguration:

```
org.springframework.cloud.bootstrap.BootstrapConfiguration=\
com.demo.LocalKubeConfig
```

The *Bean* in the *BootstrapConfiguration* will be loaded before *KubernetesClientAutoConfiguration*.

Answer (score 0):

In the main class
add @SpringBootApplication(scanBasePackages = ....)
so the customized package will be scanned
this annotation just tell spring where to search.

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-component-scanning